# Privacy of data using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I use [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/) to plot my research plots. [Here](https://plot.ly/python/privacy/) it is said that the figures made by plotly are public.

I could not figure out how someone else can see the plots I make. So I thought perhaps I misunderstood something. Can others see the plots I make using plotly python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page applies only to usage of the `chart_studio` package as shown in the examples. If you don’t install or use `chart_studio` (and you use `Plotly` version 4) your charts never leave your workstation. You can see the version 4 announcement about “offline only” for more information: https://medium.com/plotly/plotly-py-4-0-is-here-offline-only-express-first-displayable-anywhere-fc444e5659ee